# Angular withCredentials is not sending cookies

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-mvc, cookies, httpcookie

I am using Angular 8, with old backend (ASP.NET MVC 5 Framework) **NOT CORE**
I am trying to send the cookies of the website so the request from the angular website considered authenticated

I created an interceptor for this

```
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpRequest } 
from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const newRequest = request.clone({
      withCredentials: true,
    });
    return next.handle(newRequest);
  }

}
```

here is the code of the request

```
private getDefaultConfiguration(): configurationsType {
  return {
    observe: 'response',
    responseType: 'json',
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  };
}

public async get(endpoint: string, params: HttpParams = undefined) {
  const options = this.getDefaultConfiguration();
  if (params !== undefined)
    options.params = params;

  const response: HttpResponse<object> = await this.http.get(endpoint, options).toPromise();
  return await this.errorCheck(response);
}
```

I can confirm that the interceptor is executing by a `console.log` statement 
the problem is that I am not receiving the cookies in the request (by the way Http Get not Post) and my request is considered to be unauthenticated.

I am using the following Filter for CORS problem

```
public class AllowCrossSiteAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpResponseBase response = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response;

        response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
        response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
        response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

I register the filter globally,

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new AllowCrossSiteAttribute());
    }
}
```

here is the cookie that I expect to be sent in the header, this snippet is from the login method

```
var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(SessionHelper.DefaultSession().KullaniciAdi, model.RememberMe, timeout);
string encrypted = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encrypted)
{
    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(timeout),
    HttpOnly = true // cookie not available in javascript.
};

Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

and here is the cookie in the chrome

[image]
if you need any more information please ask me in the comment and I will provide that.

**Update**

1. I check it out this [article](https://www.blinkingcaret.com/2018/07/18/secure-an-asp-net-core-web-api-using-cookies/) and I applied the `same-site` attribute of the `set-cookie` to `none`, but this still does not solve the problem.
2. I updated the `[AllowCrossSiteAttribute]` to be like this, because of completely another problem I was receiving in angular

```
public class AllowCrossSiteAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpResponseBase response = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response;

        response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
        response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
        response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
        response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

3. In the `OnAuthorization` method which exists in the BaseController and which is called on each request, I tested the header of the request. 
   if I requested something from the old MVC application I receive the cookies correctly 
   [image]

    
   but when I make a request from the angular project I receive no Cookies at all

[image]

4. here is how the cookies appear in chrome inspector

   for the angular project
   [image]

   and for the old MVC project
   [image]

Comment: How is that filter registered in your app?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I register it globally, see my update

Comment: Did you performed any changes on your web.config? check https://sergeytihon.com/2017/01/25/asp-net-mvc-with-simple-windows-authorization/

Comment: @Jota.Toledo no I did not, should I apply the article exactly to my project, although I am not using Window Authorization, can you please describe in a nutshell how should I tweak the article for my specific case. thank you sir very much

Comment: so what cookies do you expect to be sent in your request?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo see the update of the question

Comment: can you check in the client that the cookie is set at the moment of sending the request?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I am sorry I did not get exactly what you mean, can you explain to me in some details what I should do, Thank you in advanced

Comment: I wanted to check the posibility that the cookie is not set in the browser before you make a request with angular after login in. Take a look at https://www.blinkingcaret.com/2018/07/18/secure-an-asp-net-core-web-api-using-cookies/ it explains some core ideas behind the cookie configuration and cross-origin requests.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Thank you for the article, it really seems that It could solve my problem. I will explore it in details and let you know about that, Thank you again.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I added an update section to my question which describes the improvement I did from the article you gave it to me, Thank you by the way. I also start a bounty on this question, because I really need to solve this, I am stuck with it from 2 weeks. Thank you a lot for all the help

Comment: _I check it out this article and I applied the same-site attribute of the set-cookie to none, but this still does not solve the problem._ add how you did this in your update

Comment: @Jota.Toledo How can I thank you I do not know. Actually I solved it immediately after updating this question. Setting the `same-site` attribute to `none` was vital but not enough, I had to add the last touch to make the magic : removing the `.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')` from the `headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')`

Comment: @Jota.Toledo please sir feel free to put an answer on this question which contains the idea of `same-site` attribute and the header, and I will accept it and grant the bounty for you. thank you because you saved my life, I was stuck with this from 2 weeks

Comment: Maybe you should put Set-Cookie header inside of Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Comment: @VladoPandžić Thank you problem solved, see my last 2 comments. thank you any way

Comment: @HakanFıstık glad to hear your problem was solved. Just to clarify; did you set the `same-site` property by setting the `HttpCookie#SameSite` property to `SameSite.None`? Can you confirm that by only removing the `'Content-Type', 'application/json'``header on the angular side was the problem solved? It would be interesting to understand why this would be the case. Could you provide a minimal setup of your MVC app that reproduces the issue? I would be interested in looking it in detail.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo HttpCookie#SameSite property exists in .NET framework 4.7.2 and above, unfortunately, my legacy project is not up to date and I am using a previous version of .NET framework, so I set this property by modifying the `web.config`. I used this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38957177/4390133

Comment: @Jota.Toledo really your idea is interesting, I will try just to remove the `Content-type` without setting the `samesite` property, I will try to provide the minimal setup of the project which reproduces the bug

Comment: Try and use ngx-cookie-service to set some dummy cookie then debug in vs try and access http context in controller then check for cookie there..

Comment: Have you tried: `newRequest = request.clone({headers: request.headers.set("withCredentials", "true")});` ?

Answer (score 2):

It is not related to your ASP.NET backend, it is related to your Angular development server that is running on port 4200, while your backend server is running on port 27309. The different ports make `http://localhost:4200` and `http://localhost:27309` different hosts, therefore the browser doesn't attach the cookie to requests going to `http://localhost:27309` despite the Angular's `withCredentials: true` flag.

To solve this, set up Angular's proxy configurations (a built in feature in angular) as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75635435/3944673) SO answer.