# file_system__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.readFileSync is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular

> ERROR TypeError: file_system__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.readFileSync
> is not a function arg1:TypeError:
> file_system__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.readFileSync is not a
> function
> {stack: 'TypeError:
> file_system__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODU…(https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9764:30)', message: 'file_system__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.readFileSync is not
> a function'}
> message:'file_system__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.readFileSync is not
> a function'

When trying to load a ca certificate in Angular 11:

```
import * as fs from 'file-system';
const httpOptions = 
            {
                headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}),
                ca: [fs.readFileSync(['cert.pem', 'key.pem'])],
                rejectUnauthorized: false
            };
```

The intention is to solve **DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT**. A browser is supposed not be allowed to access local file system for security reason, but [this](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-resolve-certificate-errors-in-nodejs-app-involving-ssl-calls-781ce48daded) `ca Option` sounds like feasible.

Comment: Why not `import {readFileSync} from "fs"` instead of using the `file-system` module, which hasn't be updated in 5 years and has a typo in the first sentence of the README.

Comment: You can't access the file system from a webpage... Is this for an electron app?

Comment: @Samathingamajig that's also a good question. I assumed this was the backend.

Comment: Well they're using webpack, and you never used webpack on the backend. Webpack just bundles files for the web (converting from `require()` and `import`/`export` into one or a few js files)

Comment: @Samathingamajig yes that's a good call

Comment: @Samathingamajig Agree as browser should be a sandbox. What I'm trying to solve is **DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT** but [this](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-resolve-certificate-errors-in-nodejs-app-involving-ssl-calls-781ce48daded) `ca Option` sounds like feasible.

Comment: @DmitryMinkovsky What I'm trying to solve is **DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT** but [this](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-resolve-certificate-errors-in-nodejs-app-involving-ssl-calls-781ce48daded) `ca Option` sounds like feasible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to solve this hassle caused by other such as front-end not sending in cookie in SSL, localhost. Please see my answer at [Angular Not Sending Cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68123821/angular-not-sending-cookie)